# Is there a way to know in ExoPlayer whether an IMA ad being played is Pre-roll, Mid-roll, Post-roll?

Tags: android, exoplayer

Is there a way to know if an ad being played currently is Pre-roll, Mid-roll or Post-roll. I can't seem to find a listener that exposes this information.
I am currently using the IMA ads event listener on the `ImaAdsLoader`:

```
imaAdsLoader.addCallback(VideoAdPlayer.VideoAdPlayerCallback);
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? If yes then please post the answer

Comment: Anyone found solution for same?